El hombre corriendo vs El hombre que corre

El hombre corriendo por el barrio es mi tío.

vs

El hombre que corre por el barrio es mi tío.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos frases? ¿Se pueden intercambiar? ¡Gracias!


El hombre corriendo por el barrio es mi tío

es equivalente a

El hombre que está corriendo por el barrio es mi tío

En ambos casos nos encontramos antes una perífrasis de gerundio, las cuales muestran una acción, un proceso o un estado de cosas en su curso. Lo cual, aplicado a este ejemplo, quiere decir que la acción está transcurriendo en este preciso momento, ahora.
Por otro lado en

El hombre que corre por el barrio es mi tío.

nos encontramos con que corre está en presente de indicativo, forma verbal que puede emplearse para indicar que la acción se realiza habitualmente, es decir mi tío corre habitualmente por el barrio, pero no tiene porque estar corriendo precisamente ahora.
La diferencia entre ambas es muy sutil. La segunda (que corre) puede sustituir a la primera (corriendo), si la acción está teniendo lugar ahora mismo; pero la primera (corriendo) no puede sustituir a la segunda (que corre), si lo que queremos indicar es que la acción se repite habitualmente.

Hablamos de perífrasis de gerundio cuando el gerundio se combina con otros verbos: estar corriendo, ir corriendo, venir corriendo, andar corriendo. En rigor, en la frase "el hombre corriendo por el barrio" el gerundio "corriendo" tiene valor calificativo: https://www.udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/el-gerundio-calificativo-un-uso-incorrecto/ y, como bien dices, proviene de una reducción de la relativa "que está corriendo" donde sí aparece la perífrasis de gerundio.
